# Rails 3: Error with Authlogic in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying create some users in the console. I'm getting the following error:

```
Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError: You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating object
```

This error occurs in an after_create which only job is to send an email to the user. If I disable this after_create, everything works, but this means no email is sent.

I tried to apply a solution found here, but it didn't work:

http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/09/working-with-authlogic-in-scriptconsole/

What's going on?

Thank you